# Listen to all onClick events of all children in jQuery

Tags: event-handling, jquery

I can listen to all mrow click events of a div, using sometihng like

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', 'mrow', function() {
    var moo = $(this).attr('id');
    if (handlers[id]) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        handlers[id]();
}
```

Can I use a similar setup to listen on *all* click events of *all* the children of the div (Without setting up, separate listeners for every type)? Some part of the tree have handler functions and some don't, and I want these requests to propagate up within the div, until one that has a handler is found.

Comment: "all the children" Direct descendants or all descendants?

Answer (score 54, accepted):

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', '*', function() {
```

`*` will bind to all element's within `#mydiv`

Demo `-->` http://jsfiddle.net/Vjwqz/1/

Comment: If I try this, http://jsfiddle.net/Vjwqz/ , it seems like nothing at all happens :/

Comment: ya, because there is no #mydiv inside #mydiv. See my answer ;)

Comment: is it possible to extract such functionality in a standalone js file, or if someone can point me if some utillity exists already. i guess this is really useful when attaching any onclick handler on any complex element with multiple children

Answer (score 16):

For all descendants:

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', '*', function() {...});
```

For direct descendants: {what is called children in javascript}

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', '> *', function() {...});
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you can leave the selector

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', function() {
```

> selector Type: String A selector string to filter the descendants of
>   the selected elements that trigger the event. If the selector is null
>   or omitted, the event is always triggered when it reaches the selected
>   element.

http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: I tried this at first but then $(this).attr('id) is always #mydiv and event.target.id is '' when i click on a nubmer within it, for example - I can't propogate up until I find a valid handler.

Answer (score -1):

refer this http://api.jquery.com/all-selector/

try :

```
$('#mydiv').on('click', '#mydiv *', function() {
var moo = $(this).attr('id');
    if (handlers[id]) {
        event.stopPropagation();
        handlers[id]();
}
```